# Fetching multiple API with correct data

Tags: javascript, leaflet, fetch, markers

Good afternoon everyone.

I have a small web app which is using API to display bike stations on a map.

I'm using this [Bike API](https://oslobysykkel.no/en/open-data/realtime)

This is my map - [Leaflet Maps](http://www.leafletjs.com)

Issue: Currently I'm fetching only one API and I take only few parameters from `JSON` response.
But I need to fetch another API as well and take only 2 parameters from it.

This is how my code currently looks like -

```
import "./styles.css";
import L from "leaflet";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";

const icon = L.icon({
  iconSize: [25, 41],
  iconAnchor: [10, 41],
  popupAnchor: [2, -40],
  iconUrl: "https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6/dist/images/marker-icon.png",
  shadowUrl: "https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6/dist/images/marker-shadow.png"
});

var map = L.map("map", {
  preferCanvas: true
}).setView([51.505, -0.09], 3);

L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
  attribution:
    '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);


fetch("https://gbfs.urbansharing.com/oslobysykkel.no/station_information.json")
  .then((responseOne) => responseOne.json())
  .then((responseDataOne) => {
    console.log(responseDataOne.data);
    const stations = responseDataOne.data.stations;

    const layerGroup = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);

    stations.forEach(({ lat, lon, name, address}) => {
      layerGroup.addLayer(
        L.marker([lat, lon], { icon }).bindPopup(
          `${name}, 
           ${address}`
        )
      );
    });

    map.fitBounds(layerGroup.getBounds());
  });
```

As you can see from this API I'm taking out `name` and `address` of the place

I need to use this API - `https://gbfs.urbansharing.com/oslobysykkel.no/station_status.json` and I'm only interested in this specific parameters (from Docs).

```
{
 "num_bikes_available": 7,
 "num_docks_available": 5,
},
```

How I can multiple fetch API and take data from both API's and merge them together, that in the end I will have something like

```
...
L.marker([lat, lon], { icon }).bindPopup(
      `${name}, 
       ${address},
       ${num_bikes_available},
       ${num_docks_available}`
    )
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Promise.all to achieve your goal like this:

```
Promise.all([
  fetch(
    "https://gbfs.urbansharing.com/oslobysykkel.no/station_information.json"
  ),
  fetch("https://gbfs.urbansharing.com/oslobysykkel.no/station_status.json")
]).then(async ([response1, response2]) => {
  const responseData1 = await response1.json();
  const responseData2 = await response2.json();

  const data1 = responseData1.data.stations;
  const data2 = responseData2.data.stations;

  // console.log(data1, data2);

  const layerGroup = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);

  data1.forEach(({ lat, lon, name, address, station_id: stationId }) => {
    layerGroup.addLayer(
      L.marker([lat, lon], { icon }).bindPopup(
        `<b>Name</b>: ${name}
        <br/>
        <b>Address</b>: ${address}
        <br/>
       <b>Number of bikes available</b>: ${
         data2.find((d) => d.station_id === stationId).num_bikes_available
       }
    <br/>
   <b>Number of docs available</b>: ${
     data2.find((d) => d.station_id === stationId).num_docks_available
   }
        `
      )
    );
  });

  map.fitBounds(layerGroup.getBounds());
});
```

You fetch first both requests. When the responses arrive you loop over the first request data. Using the `station_id` you can extract from the second's request response data `num_bikes_available` and `num_docks_available` and achieve the desired behavior.

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/displaying-json-data-on-leaflet-map-ynkv8?file=/src/index.js:1190-2234)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the most efficient way but can't you just make the second fetch in your last .then(), and write a function to merge the 2 data's you just fetched

so:

```
fetch("https://gbfs.urbansharing.com/oslobysykkel.no/station_information.json")
  .then((responseOne) => responseOne.json())
  .then((responseDataOne) => {
    console.log(responseDataOne.data);
    const stations = responseDataOne.data.stations;
    fetch("https://secondapi").then((data) => {
      //write function to merge the 2
    
    const layerGroup = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);

    mergedArray.forEach(({ lat, lon, name, address}) => {
      layerGroup.addLayer(
        L.marker([lat, lon], { icon }).bindPopup(
          `${name}, 
           ${address}`
        )
      );
    });

    map.fitBounds(layerGroup.getBounds());
 })
  });
```

Also, I'm currently working on a leaflet project myself, and I must say, if you are using ReactJs to build your website, [react-leaflet](https://react-leaflet.js.org/) is really helpfull

Comment: Thanks for advice. I'm currently not using react but maybe it can be easier solution for me as well! Thanks!